# Send SCEP request from Android

Tags: android, pki, scep

I'm looking for a way to send SCEP requests from android devices. I found some incomplete code [in this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019594/generate-a-csr-request-in-java-via-scep). Of course I could do all the work and boilerplate code myself, but I wonder if there's a more standard way to enroll android devices to our PKI. Googling around I found a lot of hits regarding jSCEP not being supported on android, but these hits are quite old and jSCEP does not seem to be a very active project.

So my question is: Do newer versions of android (marshmallow and upwards) support a standard way to create and send SCEP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after some trial & error I found out that it is possible to use jScep on Android following the instructions on the [github site of jScep](https://github.com/jscep/jscep).
The only differences are the construction of the client where i had to exchange the `ConsoleCertificateVerifier` with `OptimisticCertificateVerifier` to make it work. As the scenario takes place in an enclosed environment this doesn't raise any security issues for our case.

The other changes were to run the request in it's own Thread and handle the result in a Handler to avoid blocking the device while requesting.

In the long run we may fork jScep as it seems to be not well maintained, but that's another cup of tea. :-)